license4j activation works, but deactivation fails
I have an application that uses license4j. The License4J License Manager is using the Online.License4j server for storing generated licenses. My application uses the LicenseValidator.autoActivate(licenseObject) and LicenseValidator.autoDeactivate(licenseObject) methods to activate/deactivate licenses. So the issue is, activation works fine, the licenseObject has these fields after the method call finishes (see picture below). I also see the activation shows up in License Manager, and my number of activations has incremented. I save the license text to file.
Now, when I try to deactivate, I load the license text from file and call LicenseValidator.autoDeactivate(licenseObject): I get an error saying ACTIVATION_NOT_FOUND_ON_SERVER.
This only occurs for the new product and associated license I added recently. Previous products/licenses, which were added in the past use this exact same scheme and work fine.
activated license object

This sounds like you need support from license4j diretly: it's an issue with their system or server that we're not going to be able to help you with, and they'll certainly be in a better position to debug anyway.
